# How to get a value without the unique user ID in a users node on Firebase Realtime DB?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a user node like that:

[image]

and here, I need to access to the `appleId` field and this is my rule:

```
{
    "rules": {
      "users": {
        "$userId": {
          "single": {
            "public": {
              ".read": "true"
            }
          },
        }
      }
    }
}
```

So with that rule, I should read all the values stored in the `public` node.
Here's my code that I've written with NodeJS

```
const data = firebase
  .database()
  .ref("users/XzIvC5GUKPesQybZWfrxsSSXpMt2")
  .child('single')
  .child('public')
  .child('appleId')
  .once("value");

data.then((ss) => {
  console.log(ss.val());
});
```

And this works just fine. But I need to search for the `appleId` and so I tried this:

```
const data = firebase
  .database()
  .ref("users")
  .child("single")
  .child("public")
  .child("appleId")
  .equalTo("000072.b185925fe1f1431dad013b66f9ceb8d1.1155")
  .once("value");

data.then((ss) => {
  console.log(ss.val());
});
```

and firebase gives that error;
`(node:5131) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: permission_denied at /users/single/public/appleId: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.`

My point is to search that `appleId` without a user ID. How can I do that? Should I change my rules or is something wrong with the code?

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in the overflow menu (⠇) of [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows you to remove values you don't want to share, and allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to do is find a user based on the value of their `single/public/appleId` property. If so, the query for that would be:

```
firebase
  .database()
  .ref("users")
  .orderByChild("single/public/appleId")
  .equalTo("000072.b185925fe1f1431dad013b66f9ceb8d1.1155")
```

So the path of child to order/filter on is passed into `orderByChild`, not as a set of `child()` calls.

---

But this still won't work with your security rules, as you'll need to have read permission on `/users` in order to be able to execute this query.

For this reason you should put data that has separate access requirements into separate top-level nodes. The `public` in your data structure is a typical sign that you want to pull this data up into its own higher-level node, where you can grant everyone read access so:

```
"users": {
  "uid1": { ... }
},
"users_public": {
  "uid1": {
    "appleId": "000072.b185925fe1f1431dad013b66f9ceb8d1.1155"
  }
}
```

With this structure, you can then query the data with:

```
firebase
  .database()
  .ref("users_public")
  .orderByChild("appleId")
  .equalTo("000072.b185925fe1f1431dad013b66f9ceb8d1.1155")
```

---

The only alternative to this is if the value you want to filter on is present in the user's auth token (for example their UID). So say, you add the Apple ID to the user's auth token as a [custom claim](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) called `appleId`, then you can allow [securely querying the data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/rules-conditions#query-based_rules) in your existing structure with something like:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      ".read": "query.orderByChild == 'single/public/appleId' &&
                query.equalTo == auth.token.appleId" 
    }
  }
}
```